# Global Name <function> not defined error Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a function

```
def details(href):
    response = requests.get(href)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    genre =  soup.find(text="Genre: ").next_sibling.text
    print genre
```

that I am trying to call inside another function

```
def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=' + str(page) + '&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2013&p=.htm'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.select('td > b > font > a[href^=/movies/?]'):
            href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')
            details(href)
            title = link.string
            listOfTitles.append(title)
        page += 1
spider(1)
```

I am getting an error

line 27, in 
    spider(1)
  line 22, in spider
    details(href)
NameError: global name 'details' is not defined

I already tried the self.details(href) method, but there was an additional error saying it could not resolve "self". How can I fix this?

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. What is the `**` doing around `details(href)`? You cannot highlight code in code block. Or is that part of your python file?

Comment: I tried to bold it but the website just formatted it that way. In the actual code, it's not there.

Comment: And this is all in one file? With the details defined before spider?

Comment: Yes, this is all one file. Details isn't defined before spider, but its a separate function I'm trying to call inside spider.

Comment: That is the problem, move the `spider(1)` call down, as per my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I'll accept your answer once the time limit is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you call `spider(1)` before the `def details()` in the file, that function `details()` is not known yet.

You should at least move the call `spider(1)` behind the function definition starting with `def details()`, you can leave the `def spider():` lines before the `def details()` as long as calling `spider()` happens when everything needed by `spider()` is "known", i.e. parsed in the file processed so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you define detail function like this:

```
  def details(self, href):
      ......
```

Then, you could call self.details. Although I don't quite get your error...

Comment: I'm still getting the unresolved reference to self error :/

Comment: if you define everything under a class, such as 
     
      def spider(self, max_pages):

I believe, you didn't define spider well, too.